# Length of Gaps in Clockable Values

Tags: lo.logic, ordinal-computability

As I understand, there can't be any (total) OTM computable function (in traditional input/output sense) $f:Ord \rightarrow Ord$ such that $f(x)$ gives an upper-bound on the length of the $x$-th gap.

To clarify it a bit, consider the total function $g:c \rightarrow c$ ($c$ is supposed to be supremum of clockable values) such that $g(x)$ returns the length of the $x$-th gap. We require the function $f$ to have the property $f(x) \geq g(x)$ for all $x<c$. For $x \geq c$ the function $f$ can return any value (however, it has to return some value). As I understand, if we drop the last requirement of totality on $f$ (for $x \geq c$), it is not difficult to describe the program computing such an $f$.

If what I have written isn't correct, then clearly I am misunderstanding something very basic. My question is simply is there a relatively simple way to get an intuition for how this function grows. As an example, is there a relatively simple upper-bound for a value $\alpha$ such that the  first gap that occurs after $\omega^{CK}_{\alpha}$ has a length greater than $\omega^{CK}_{\alpha+1}$?

Comment: I take it "clockable" is a technical term that people in logic and/or computability all understand.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, it is a common term. A given value/ordinal $\alpha$ is clockable iff: there exists an infinite program (in certain specific given model) starting from empty input that halts exactly on the step $\alpha$ in its running time.